# Tensorflow lite for micro: what are the differences among tflite::tensor, TfLiteTensor and TfLiteEvalTensor at a high level view?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I am trying to examine the tensorflow source code to understand how it works, especially how tensorflow lite for microcontrollers models are loaded, run inferences, etc. in a microcontroller.

As I have been figuring out so far, it seems that `tflite::tensor`, which is defined in `schema_generated.h` represents a tensor saved in a .tflite model, such as fixed weights for kernels in a convolution layer, and that `TfLiteEvalTensor` is a lightweight struct that represents a tensor needed at runtime, with minimum information attached. Also, it looks like the latter is initialized from the former.

Sometimes the comments were quite helpful, but I was not able to get some sort of high-level descriptions that could help to distinguish the three structs `tflite::tensor`, `TfLiteTensor` and `TfLiteEvalTensor` clearly, in terms of what they are aimed to represent, what their functions are, what are the reasons or motivation for such distinguishing, etc.

Can anybody give me some hints, or direct me where I can find any good references that I could refer to? Thank you very much in advance.